# Office-Js Add-in Debugging with Angular-CLI and F12chooser: No map files shown

Tags: angular, angular-cli, office-js

Last time I was developing Office Add-ins I was using Angular with Webpack.

Now I want to try it with **Angular-CLI**.

All works as expected, except one thing: F12Chooser Debugging

It used to take advantage of `map` files, therefore I could debug my add-ins with `F12Chooser`. Now I don't see them. Please see screenshots below (Chrome Debug cosole compared with F12Chooser).

Both are same app, served with HTTPS.

Do I need to make changes in default Angular-CLI settings I would ask, but then again, how come same app looks different in debugging tools, that I can't make sense of.

I'm using `Angular-CLI v1.3.0-rc1` by the way.

[image: F12Chooser Debugger]

[image: Chrome Debug Tools]

Comment: I've typed address in Internet Explorer and launched F12Chooser to test. F12Chooser shows, as expected, all mapped files in this situation but not while lunching under Office Add-In. It wasn't the case few months back when I was using Angular w. Webpack directly, but also I've updated my Office package. So I expect problem is caused by updated Office, not Angular-Cli itself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer/solution per se, but a workaround to achieve **debugging**.

I've ended up adding my "Add-In" manifest file in Office 365 (Word Online) and debug from there.

See screenshots below.

[image: HOW TO ADD YOUR MANIFEST FILE]

Adding a `localhost` served app-manifest is perfectly fine here, since this is only for debugging, it works.

[image: CHROME DEBUG TOOLS]

Once you open Devtools, try to search name **baseFrameName** (under 'sdx_ow_iframe') in Sources section. Your Angular-Cli initialized Webpack session resides there and you'll see all your `ts` files.

**DOWNSIDE**

Apparently API for Office Online does not support all functionality desktop version does. For example set values for table did not work on online version.